# Use web app permissions in Site Collection app catalog

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I've created a spfx package containing a webpart that reads from MS Graph. The solution request the following permissions in package-solution.json:

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Directory.Read.All,Directory.ReadWrite.All"
      }
    ]
```

This works fine when I deploy the solution to the tenant app catalog. When I deploy the solution to a site collection app catalog it gets deployed without any error and creates an API access request (which I approve). But the webpart throws the following error when using the MSGraphClient:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [403] Forbidden ::> {"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2021-05-20T19:40:49","request-id":"82b80ddb-...","client-request-id":"82b80ddb-..."}}}
```

Is this scenario not supported or have I missed any steps required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webApiPermissionRequests is an array of webApiPermissionRequest items. Each item defines the resource and the scope of the permission request.

Change your permissions to the below

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
      },
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
      }
    ]
```

Besides, after your  deploy the solution to the tenant app catalog. You need to approve  the requested Microsoft Graph permissions in SharePoint Admin Center: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-microsoft-graph-apis#approve-the-requested-microsoft-graph-permissions

Comment: Thanks, i've messed up my permission request.